# How to filter similar edges in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list which contains all the edges of an undirected weighted graph.I further sorted it in increasing order of their edge weights.

The list is as follows

```
lis = [['B', 'C', 1], ['C', 'B', 1], ['B', 'A', 2], ['C', 'A', 2], ['A', 'C', 2], ['A', 'B', 2], ['D', 'C', 3], ['C', 'D', 3], ['B', 'D', 5], ['D', 'B', 5]]
```

Now in the list, `['B', 'C', 1], ['C', 'B', 1]` means the same thing.That is an edge `BC` has a weight of 1 and edge `CB` has a weight of 1.Similarly we have edges `AB`, `BA` and so on in the list.

How do I keep only one of the two edges and not both since they both mean the same thing.So for `['B', 'C', 1], ['C', 'B', 1]`, I only want to keep say `['B', 'C', 1]`.How do I do that?

I found a similar question but I am not really sure how to implement it in my case.
[Removing duplicate edges from graph in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555385/removing-duplicate-edges-from-graph-in-python-list)

I tried to implement the solution posted in the link for my situtation but doesn't work

```
def normalize(t):
    [n1, n2, dist] = t
    if n1 < n2:
        return t
    else:
        return [n2, n1, dist]

unique_edges = set(map(normalize, lis))
```

Comment: What have you attempted? What are you struggling with w.r.t. the other question?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how it "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? If so, provide a traceback. Is it producing the incorrect result? If so, show what it's producing for the sample input you provided.

Comment: @glibdud I am not sure how the normalize function works and so just changed the structure provided to the function since mine is a list inside a list and the asker had a tuple inside a list.I am getting a unhashable type: 'list' error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort each item and remove duplicates:

```
>>> lis = sorted([sorted(item) for item in lis])
>>> [lis[i][::-1] for i in range(len(lis)) if i == 0 or lis[i] != lis[i-1]]
[['C', 'B', 1], ['B', 'A', 2], ['C', 'A', 2], ['D', 'C', 3], ['D', 'B', 5]]
```

Comment: The first line of the code itself produces TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()